# VB.NET accessing class objects from launched thread

Tags: vb.net, synchronization

I am writing an application in VB.NET that allows users to schedule submissions (emails) to be sent at a later date. I use threads to wait until the time is right to send a particular submission, but for some reason I can't access one of the class objects from the listener threads (or something else is happening, that's what I'm trying to figure out). Here is the relevant code:

```
Public Class AppContext
  Inherits ApplicationContext

  Private submsnMngr As SubmissionManager

  Public Sub New()
    submsnMgr = New SubmissionManager()
    menuAddEdit = New ToolStripMenuItem("Add/Edit Submissions")
    ...
  End Sub

  Private Sub menuAddEdit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Handles menuAddEdit.Click
    ' The user clicking this tray button is the ONLY way that the form can be shown
    submsnMngr.ShowWelcome()
  End Sub

  ...

End Class

Class SubmissionManager

  Public currentSubmissions As SubmissionList
  Public WelcomeForm As Welcome

  Public Sub ShowWelcome()
    If WelcomeForm Is Nothing Then
      ' Welcome is the form that needs to be refreshed down in the MailSender subroutine
      WelcomeForm = New Welcome(Me)
    End If
    WelcomeForm.Show()
  End Sub

  Public Sub CheckDates()
    For Each submsn In currentSubmissions.Submissions
      SyncLock submsn
        If Today.Date >= submsn.EffDate.AddDays(-90).Date And Not submsn.Sent90 And Not submsn.Denied90 And submsn.Thread Is Nothing Then
          submsn.Send(1)
          submsn.Sent90 = True
          currentSubmissions.Save()
        ElseIf Today.Date = submsn.EffDate.AddDays(-91).Date And submsn.Thread Is Nothing Then
          Dim thd As New Thread(AddressOf MailSender)
          thd.IsBackground = True
          submsn.Thread = thd
          Dim args As New ThreadArgs(submsn.Insured, 1)
          thd.Start(args)
        End If
        If Today.Date >= submsn.EffDate.AddDays(-60).Date And submsn.Thread Is Nothing Then
          submsn.Send(2)
          currentSubmissions.RemoveSubmission(submsn)
          If WelcomeForm IsNot Nothing Then
            WelcomeForm.RefreshSubmissions()
          End If
        ElseIf Today.Date = submsn.EffDate.AddDays(-61).Date And submsn.Thread Is Nothing Then
          Dim thd As New Thread(AddressOf MailSender)
          thd.IsBackground = True
          submsn.Thread = thd
          Dim args As New ThreadArgs(submsn.Insured, 2)
          thd.Start(args)
        End If
      End SyncLock
    Next
  End Sub

  Private Sub DateListener()
    Do
      CheckDates()
      Thread.Sleep(3600000)
    Loop
  End Sub

  Private Sub MailSender(args As ThreadArgs)
    Dim wait As New TimeSpan(14 - DateTime.Now.Hour, 23 - DateTime.Now.Minute, 0)
    Thread.Sleep(wait.TotalMilliseconds)

    Dim submsn As Submission = currentSubmissions.GetSubmission(args.insured)
    SyncLock submsn
      submsn.Send(args.mode)
      If args.mode = 1 Then
        submsn.Sent90 = True
        submsn.Thread = Nothing
        currentSubmissions.Save()
      Else
        currentSubmissions.RemoveSubmission(submsn)
      End If
    End SyncLock
    If WelcomeForm IsNot Nothing Then
      ' Here is the issue, this code is not being run, even though WelcomeForm is set
      ' in New() above
      WelcomeForm.RefreshSubmissions()
    End If
  End Sub

End Class
```

Paying special attention to the few comment lines in the code above, why is `WelcomeForm` `Nothing` when I clearly set it to reference the form created in the `New()` subroutine? I tried alternatively sending the reference to the `MailSender` thread as an argument, but the same thing happened. Note that I need the `If` statement there because the user may have closed the form before the thread gets to that point. But it is essential that `RefreshSubmissions()` be called on it if it is still open.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling RefreshSubmissions() directly from your thread.  You should use Invoke() to marshal the call to the GUI thread...

Comment: The `Invoke()` code is in `RefreshSubmissions()` itself.

Comment: Ha...cool beans then!  Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, realized my thread was being aborted elsewhere in my application's code. No problems with the actual code I posted above.